# Installing Basemap for python

Tags: mac, python, python3, matplotlib

Trying to install basemap via this website 
[Basemap Matplotlib Toolkit](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html)

I have followed everything they say until this part of the installation:

`if libgeos_c is in /usr/local/lib and geos_c.h is in /usr/local/include, set GEOS_DIR to /usr/local`

The goal for this step is to set the environment variable GEOS_DIR to point to the location /usr/local.

However, I am not sure how to set an environment variable to point to a certain location. I looked at other answers saying I need to create a plist, but I don't know much about it. I'm using MacOS mojave :)